# How does socketIO handle the functions I give to him?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

It's a project including angularJs, nodeJs and mongoDb.

I have this client side code :

```
webSocket.emit('createNode', node, function(node){
                                       /*   ^   */
                            /*  Where does this goes ?  */
    $scope.nodes.push(node);
});
```

And this server side code :

```
socket.on('createNode', function(node, callback) {
                                    /*    ^    */
                           /*  Where does this comes from ? */
    mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
        db.collection('nodes').insertOne(node, function(error, data){
            callback(node);                   
        });                         
    });
});
```

I want to know how does socketIo do to run the function I gave him and how can I execute a piece of code after an emit success without calling it explicitly server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the so called `acknowledgement`. You can check the docs here: http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements).

It's very simple idea - when you emit something from the client, the client saves your acknowledgment callback and maps it to your specific emit call. "emit `createNode` - function() {}". Then it sends the info to the server and marks that this emit needs callback. When the server calls it, it's **not** actually calling the function on the client, it's just internally saying to socket "okay send back the acknowledgment".

Socket.IO actually makes **another** emit back from the server and because it's marked as acknowledgment, the client treats it like so. It browses the map it has created and calls the function that was stored previously.

It's all done internally so that you don't write logic for waiting for that callback - it's all under the hood for you.

Back to your last question - "how can I execute a piece of code after an emit success". There is no such a thing as "emit success". The client does **not** know if the emit reached the server or what has happened there. Sockets are simply a channel that **sends** information - they do not care what's going on next. That's the way it's built.

If you **need** to know if server got your command, you must send back that information to the client. Which means, in terms of Socket.IO, that you should use those acknowledgments and explicitly notify about success.

But don't be afraid of that - **explicitly** does **NOT** mean you are calling client side function, it's just notifying client that all went well and command was received. This approach is very powerful as you can pass params about the result of the command, stating if it was valid or not, if the result is success or not. So go ahead, give it a try :)